# Best practice for share "Redux Logic" between multiple projects

Tags: redux, react-redux

We working on a new project with a stack of Node.js in the BE + React and Redux in the FE.

Basically, this project is a "thin" version of an existing project  - so it will have some basic features of the existing project + some new features.

I am looking for a way to reduce the copy-paste and duplication of code in those 2 projects(and can be more "duplicate" projects like this in the future).

In the BE we don't have any problem - the BE is the same for all FE projects.

On the other side, we have a UI library that we use - so all the atomic components are reused and we do not have any "copy-paste" here too.

The parts that we found ourselves copy-paste between multiple projects are all the "Redux" part - reducers, selectors, actions, etc.

There are any best practices/libraries/design patterns that we can follow to write the "Redux" parts once and use them in multiple projects?

Answer (score 0):

The way I implement this is to have reusable logic hold its state as a separate branch in the store. So for example:

const state = {
user: defaultUserState,
messages: defaultMessagingState,
search: defaultSearchState
}

The reducers are similarly implemented in separate sub-components and combined:

combineReducers({
user: userReducer,
messages: messagingReducer,
search: searchReducer
})

I use redux-logic which is implemented as middleware. I am expecting to be able to do the same thing with the side effects.
The current leakage is related to navigation - which feature components are shown depending on which actions have been fired is defined in the main next project in the top level navigation reducer.